# rendering a component repeatedly based on array fetched from API

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a stock market app (side project.) As you can see I'm using the useState hook to pull out the data from the finnhub API and the response is an array of objects (list of stock market companies.)

```
Const [finance, setFinance] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=xxxxxxxxxx`
            )
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data[0]);
                setFinance(res.data[0]);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
```

Currently, the results of said array (Nasdaq 100 companies) are being rendered in my Card component.

```
return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography
                    className={classes.companyName}
                    color='textSecondary'
                    gutterBottom
                >
                    {finance.description}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant='h5' className={classes.stockSymbol}>
                    {finance.displaySymbol}
                </Typography>
```

My question is that, Is there any way I can render my component repeatedly based on the number of objects from the API response? (I.E. 100 companies = 100 card components) without me having to pass in 100 props to a single component. Thanks for anyone willing to help

Comment: If it is an array, you can render it as a list https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Yeah but I need to render it as a card component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map to iterate through the list of companies and pass it to the Card component, like so:

```
  {
    finance.map((item, index) => <CardCopmonent company={item} key={index} />
  }
```

Then in your Card component, you will be able to access the company through `props.company`